# Oracle PL/SQL - Iterate on column names of locally defined table

Tags: database, oracle, loops, plsql, database-cursor

I would like to iterate on the names of a locally defined table, but it doesn't work as expected:

```sql
declare
   type books is record
        (title   varchar(50)  := 'First Book'
        ,author  varchar(50)  := 'Me'
        ,subject varchar(100) := 'Simple ones'
        ,book_id number       := 94321
        );      
   type table_of_books is 
      table of books;
   list_of_books table_of_books;
   
   CURSOR c IS
     SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_COL_COMMENTS WHERE table_name='list_of_books';
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  list_of_books := table_of_books();
  list_of_books.extend(1);
  list_of_books(1) := books();
  
  FOR current_field IN c LOOP -- Is not iterating
    dbms_output.put_line(current_field.column_name); -- I would expect output here
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

This is Oracle 19c.

Comment: list_of_books is not a table and it will not have entry in all_col_comments view

Comment: The data dictionary to get the table names accessible to the logged in user will be ideally ALL_TABLES.

Comment: @rainu Trying `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE table_name='list_of_books';` I'm getting `ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier `

Comment: Give a try at ALL_TAB_COLUMNS pls use upper case while checking table names .
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.html#GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63

Comment: @rainu using `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` also doesn't work for me. If if have a working demos please provide it.

Comment: I might have miss read the question ALL_TAB_COLUMNS have entry if its a table and not locally defined record type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an object created in the SQL scope rather than a record created in the PL/SQL scope then you can use `ANYDATA` to find out the attributes and their values.

For example, if your types are:

```sql
CREATE TYPE book is OBJECT(
  title           varchar(50),
  author          varchar(50),
  subject         varchar(100),
  book_id         number,
  first_published DATE
);

CREATE TYPE table_of_books IS TABLE OF book;
```

Then you can create the package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE reflection IS
  TYPE type_info IS RECORD(
    prec        PLS_INTEGER,
    scale       PLS_INTEGER,
    len         PLS_INTEGER,
    csid        PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm       PLS_INTEGER,
    schema_name VARCHAR2(30),
    type_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    version     VARCHAR2(100),
    count       PLS_INTEGER
  );

  TYPE attr_info IS RECORD(
    prec           PLS_INTEGER,
    scale          PLS_INTEGER,
    len            PLS_INTEGER,
    csid           PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm          PLS_INTEGER,
    attr_elt_type  ANYTYPE,
    aname          VARCHAR2(30)
  );

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/
```

With the package body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY reflection IS
  DEBUG BOOLEAN := FALSE;

  FUNCTION get_type(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN ANYTYPE
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anydata.GetType( typ => v_anytype );
    RETURN v_anytype;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_info(
    p_anytype IN ANYTYPE
  ) RETURN type_info
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anytype.GetInfo (
      v_type_info.prec, 
      v_type_info.scale,
      v_type_info.len, 
      v_type_info.csid,
      v_type_info.csfrm,
      v_type_info.schema_name, 
      v_type_info.type_name, 
      v_type_info.version,
      v_type_info.count
    );

    IF v_typeid <> DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not an object.' );
    END IF;

    RETURN v_type_info;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN Get_Info( Get_Type( p_anydata ) ).COUNT;
  END;
  
  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata     ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype     ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info   REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output      VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
    v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
    
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
      pos            => p_index,
      prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
      scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
      len            => v_attr_info.len,
      csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
      csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
      attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
      aname          => v_attr_info.aname
    );
    RETURN v_attr_info.aname;
  END;
        
  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata   ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output    VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
    
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    
    FOR i IN 1 .. p_index LOOP
      DECLARE
        v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
        v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
        v_result_code PLS_INTEGER;
      BEGIN
        v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
          pos            => i,
          prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
          scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
          len            => v_attr_info.len,
          csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
          csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
          attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
          aname          => v_attr_info.aname
        );

        IF DEBUG THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Attribute ' || i || ': '
            || v_attr_info.aname
            || ' (type ' || v_attr_typeid || ')'
          );
        END IF;

        CASE v_attr_typeid
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value NUMBER;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetNumber( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value );
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetVarchar2( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN v_value;
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value DATE;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetDate( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
            END IF;
          END;
        ELSE
          NULL;
        END CASE;
      END;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then your code to get the values could be:

```sql
DECLARE
   list_of_books table_of_books;
   idx           PLS_INTEGER := 1;
   p_anydata     ANYDATA;
   p_attr_name   VARCHAR2(30);
   p_attr_value  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  list_of_books := table_of_books(
    book(
      'First book',
      'Me',
      'Simple Ones',
      94321,
      DATE '1970-01-01'
    ),
    book(
      'Second book',
      'You',
      'Intermediate Ones',
      55555,
      DATE '2020-01-01'
    ),
    book(
      'Third book',
      NULL,
      'Advanced Ones',
      77777,
      DATE '2099-12-31' + INTERVAL '0 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND
    )
  );
  
  FOR book_no IN 1 .. list_of_books.COUNT LOOP
    p_anydata := ANYDATA.ConvertObject( list_of_books(book_no) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Book ' || book_no || ':' );
    FOR attr_no IN 1 .. REFLECTION.get_size( p_anydata ) LOOP
      p_attr_name  := REFLECTION.get_attr_name_at( p_anydata, attr_no );
      p_attr_value := REFLECTION.get_attr_value_at( p_anydata, attr_no );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '  ' || p_attr_name || ': ' || p_attr_value );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Book 1:
>   TITLE: First book
>   AUTHOR: Me
>   SUBJECT: Simple Ones
>   BOOK_ID: 94321
>   FIRST_PUBLISHED: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
> Book 2:
>   TITLE: Second book
>   AUTHOR: You
>   SUBJECT: Intermediate Ones
>   BOOK_ID: 55555
>   FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2020-01-01 00:00:00
> Book 3:
>   TITLE: Third book
>   AUTHOR: 
>   SUBJECT: Advanced Ones
>   BOOK_ID: 77777
>   FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2099-12-31 23:59:59
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de13d04cd2074e7311ee748c5919817d)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's way too complex. I'm looking for something simple. PL/SQL should provide some way of doing this.

Comment: @user5507535 "PL/SQL should provide some way of doing this." However, it doesn't provide a native way of doing this and we can't just wish something into being so. Once you have created the package then there is hardly much more code than in your question (the majority of the last PL/SQL block is creating sample data, getting the attributes is a simple `FOR ... LOOP` with calls to the package).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't. There's no facility to iterate through record attributes in PL/SQL like that.

Long answer: You can use the `table` operator to read arrays using SQL. So you can `unpivot` the structure, returning the column names as rows.

To do this, you need to define the record and array either:

- In a package spec
- As SQL object types

Sticking with PL/SQL types gives something like:

```
create or replace package pkg as 

   type books is record
        (title   varchar(50)  := 'First Book'
        ,author  varchar(50)  := 'Me'
        ,subject varchar(100) := 'Simple ones'
        ,book_id number       := 94321
        );      
   type table_of_books is 
      table of books
      index by pls_integer;

end;
/

declare
   
   list_of_books pkg.table_of_books;
   cursor c is
     select * from table ( list_of_books )
     unpivot (
       val for c in ( 
         title, author, subject
       )
     );
begin
  list_of_books := pkg.table_of_books (
    1 => pkg.books ( 
      'First book', 'me', 'this', 100
    )
  );

  for current_field in c loop 
    dbms_output.put_line(current_field.c); 
  end loop;
end;
/

TITLE
AUTHOR
SUBJECT
```

Some notes:

- You need to know the names of the attributes you want to become rows in the `unpivot` clause
- To `unpivot` columns, they need to have the same data type, so you'll need a subquery to `to_char` everything

If you're on 19c, you could also look into [converting the objects to JSON](https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/json_object-enhancements-19c)

Comment: Yes, it's Oracla 19c. I will take a look in the JSON link, to see if it would be simpler.

Comment: I can't see how I can use JSON for this. If someone helps old it would be great.

Comment: You can turn the document into a `json_object_t` and call the `get_keys()` method on this

Answer (score 2):

Attributes of the types declared in the PL/SQL scope are not stored as metadata in the data dictionary.

---

One possible solution is to get the column names as a result of *unnesting query* with  the `TABLE` operator. The collection must be known to the SQL parser, i.e. at least declared in the package. In this case the data in the collection is not needed, just open the cursor with an empty collection:

```
create or replace package libapi as 
    type book is record (
        title varchar(50),
        author varchar(50),
        subject varchar(100),
        book_id number);      
    type books is table of book index by pls_integer;
end;
/
declare
    lib libapi.books;
    nc number; 
    cols number;
    ds dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from table (lib);
    nc := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number (rc);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns (nc, cols, ds);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor (nc);
    for i in 1..cols loop dbms_output.put_line (ds(i).col_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Outcome:

```
TITLE
AUTHOR
SUBJECT
BOOK_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using JSON_OBJECT_T:

```sql
DECLARE
  books CONSTANT JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(
  '{
    "title":   "First Book", 
    "author":  "Me",
    "subject": "Simple ones",
    "book_id": 94321
  }');

  book_keys JSON_KEY_LIST := books.get_keys;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..book_keys.COUNT LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( book_keys(i) || ': ' ||  books.get_string(book_keys(i)) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```