# Oracle access the record type values using dot notation with identifiers from varray

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am going to access the values from oracle record using the dot notation and identifier as variable, i am getting error V_COL must be declared.

```
declare 
    cursor c1 is select * from temp_sample_records;
    type t is table of  temp_sample_records%rowtype;
    l_tab t;
    rec c1%rowtype;
    term term_cell_data@ktkcm%rowtype;
    term_reverify term_cell_data_reverify@ktkcm%rowtype;
    type t_cols IS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(100);
    cols t_cols; 
    V_COL varchar2(100);
begin
    cols := t_cols('GSMNUMBER','CAF_SERIAL_NO','CUSTOMER_NAME');
    open c1;

    loop
        fetch c1 bulk collect into l_tab limit 5000;
        exit when l_tab.count=0;
        for i in l_tab.first..l_tab.last loop

            begin
                select * into term from term_cell_data@ktkcm where gsmnumber=l_tab(i).msisdn and caf_serial_no=l_tab(i).caf_serial_no;
                for c in 1..cols.last loop
                    V_COL :=cols(c);
                    dbms_output.put_line(term.V_COL);
                end loop;
            exception
                when no_data_found then null;
            end;

        end loop;
    end loop;

    close c1;
end;
/
```

kindly help where i am making a mistake

Error ORA-06550: line 22, column 51:
PLS-00302: component 'V_COL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 22, column 25:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

> where i am making a mistake

`term.V_COL` is not valid as, I am assuming that, you do not have a column named `V_COL` in the `term_cell_data@ktkcm` table and you are trying to dynamically access the columns. You cannot do this.

You could look at [reflection using `ANYDATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913702/1509264), however that does not work with record data types and would need Object data types defined in the SQL scope.

You could also look at the [`DBMS_SQL` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913702/1509264) but I think that, even if you worked to get the data using position indexes rather than column names, you would still need to know the data type of every column.

You would probably be best to just statically name each column in the `%ROWTYPE` variable (rather than trying to dynamically reference columns). So in your inner-most loop, you could use:

```sql
select *
into   term
from   term_cell_data@ktkcm
where  gsmnumber=l_tab(i).msisdn
and    caf_serial_no=l_tab(i).caf_serial_no;

dbms_output.put_line(term.GSMNUMBER);
dbms_output.put_line(term.CAF_SERIAL_NO);
dbms_output.put_line(term.CUSTOMER_NAME);
```