# PLSQL : Return Concatenated string of all attributes of a Object

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
--Declare Object
create or replace TYPE INP_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(    attribute_1    VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
    ,attribute_2    VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
);

--Create Package
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST AS 
  PROCEDURE PROC1 (l_inp_obj  IN  INP_OBJ) ;
END TEST;

--Create Package Body
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
    PROCEDURE PROC1 (l_inp_obj IN INP_OBJ) IS
    BEGIN    
        dbms_output.put_line(l_inp_obj.attribute_1 || ' ~ '|| l_inp_obj.attribute_2);

-- have to write every element individually here 
    END PROC1;
END TEST;


-- Calling Procedure 
DECLARE
  L_INP_OBJ INP_OBJ;
BEGIN
    L_INP_OBJ := (INP_OBJ('VALUE OF ATTR 1'
                         ,'VALUE OF ATTR 2'));
  TEST.PROC1(L_INP_OBJ => L_INP_OBJ);
END;
```

for display I had to write every attribute of input object individually. Is there a better way to return concatenated string of all values of Input Object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913702/1509264), you can write a package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE reflection IS
  TYPE type_info IS RECORD(
    prec        PLS_INTEGER,
    scale       PLS_INTEGER,
    len         PLS_INTEGER,
    csid        PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm       PLS_INTEGER,
    schema_name VARCHAR2(30),
    type_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    version     VARCHAR2(100),
    count       PLS_INTEGER
  );

  TYPE attr_info IS RECORD(
    prec           PLS_INTEGER,
    scale          PLS_INTEGER,
    len            PLS_INTEGER,
    csid           PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm          PLS_INTEGER,
    attr_elt_type  ANYTYPE,
    aname          VARCHAR2(30)
  );

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/
```

With the body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY reflection IS
  DEBUG BOOLEAN := FALSE;

  FUNCTION get_type(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN ANYTYPE
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anydata.GetType( typ => v_anytype );
    RETURN v_anytype;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_info(
    p_anytype IN ANYTYPE
  ) RETURN type_info
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anytype.GetInfo (
      v_type_info.prec, 
      v_type_info.scale,
      v_type_info.len, 
      v_type_info.csid,
      v_type_info.csfrm,
      v_type_info.schema_name, 
      v_type_info.type_name, 
      v_type_info.version,
      v_type_info.count
    );

    IF v_typeid <> DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not an object.' );
    END IF;

    RETURN v_type_info;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN Get_Info( Get_Type( p_anydata ) ).COUNT;
  END;
  
  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata     ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype     ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info   REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output      VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
    v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
    
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
      pos            => p_index,
      prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
      scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
      len            => v_attr_info.len,
      csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
      csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
      attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
      aname          => v_attr_info.aname
    );
    RETURN v_attr_info.aname;
  END;
        
  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata   ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output    VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
    
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    
    FOR i IN 1 .. p_index LOOP
      DECLARE
        v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
        v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
        v_result_code PLS_INTEGER;
      BEGIN
        v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
          pos            => i,
          prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
          scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
          len            => v_attr_info.len,
          csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
          csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
          attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
          aname          => v_attr_info.aname
        );

        IF DEBUG THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Attribute ' || i || ': '
            || v_attr_info.aname
            || ' (type ' || v_attr_typeid || ')'
          );
        END IF;

        CASE v_attr_typeid
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value NUMBER;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetNumber( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value );
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetVarchar2( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN v_value;
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value DATE;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetDate( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
            END IF;
          END;
        ELSE
          NULL;
        END CASE;
      END;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can iterate over the object to find the attributes and write the package as:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE TEST AS 
  PROCEDURE PROC1 (p_anydata IN ANYDATA);
END TEST;
/
```

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
  PROCEDURE PROC1 (p_anydata IN ANYDATA)
  IS
    p_attr_name  VARCHAR2(30);
    p_attr_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    FOR attr_no IN 1 .. REFLECTION.get_size(p_anydata) LOOP
      p_attr_name  := REFLECTION.get_attr_name_at(p_anydata, attr_no);
      p_attr_value := REFLECTION.get_attr_value_at(p_anydata, attr_no);
      IF attr_no > 1 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( ' ~ ' );
      END IF;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( p_attr_value );
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
  END PROC1;
END TEST;
/
```

Then call it using:

```sql
DECLARE
  L_INP_OBJ INP_OBJ;
BEGIN
  L_INP_OBJ := INP_OBJ('VALUE OF ATTR 1' ,'VALUE OF ATTR 2');
  TEST.PROC1(P_ANYDATA => ANYDATA.ConvertObject(L_INP_OBJ);
END;
/
```