Oracle PL/SQL - Iterate table of objects through reflection
This is an extension of an answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64913702/4351488. In the solution provided, primitive data types are handled but I also need to handle nested collections iteratively. For the sake of simplicity, the example only provides a single instance of a named collection but the idea is that the implementation supports deeply nested collections.
Take the following data types:
CREATE TYPE book_page is OBJECT( 
  book_page       number,
  content         varchar2(4000)
);
/

CREATE TYPE table_of_book_pages IS TABLE OF book_page;
/

CREATE TYPE book is OBJECT(
  title           varchar(50),
  author          varchar(50),
  subject         varchar(100),
  book_id         number,
  first_published DATE,
  book_pages      table_of_book_pages
);
/

CREATE TYPE table_of_books IS TABLE OF book;
/

With the reflection package provided in the original answer
CREATE PACKAGE reflection IS
  TYPE type_info IS RECORD(
    prec        PLS_INTEGER,
    scale       PLS_INTEGER,
    len         PLS_INTEGER,
    csid        PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm       PLS_INTEGER,
    schema_name VARCHAR2(30),
    type_name   VARCHAR2(30),
    version     VARCHAR2(100),
    count       PLS_INTEGER
  );

  TYPE attr_info IS RECORD(
    prec           PLS_INTEGER,
    scale          PLS_INTEGER,
    len            PLS_INTEGER,
    csid           PLS_INTEGER,
    csfrm          PLS_INTEGER,
    attr_elt_type  ANYTYPE,
    aname          VARCHAR2(30)
  );

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY reflection IS
  FUNCTION get_type(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN ANYTYPE
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anydata.GetType( typ => v_anytype );
    RETURN v_anytype;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_info(
    p_anytype IN ANYTYPE
  ) RETURN type_info
  IS
    v_typeid    PLS_INTEGER;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_typeid := p_anytype.GetInfo (
      v_type_info.prec, 
      v_type_info.scale,
      v_type_info.len, 
      v_type_info.csid,
      v_type_info.csfrm,
      v_type_info.schema_name, 
      v_type_info.type_name, 
      v_type_info.version,
      v_type_info.count
    );

    IF v_typeid <> DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Not an object.' );
    END IF;

    RETURN v_type_info;
  END;

  FUNCTION get_size(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA
  ) RETURN PLS_INTEGER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN Get_Info( Get_Type( p_anydata ) ).COUNT;
  END;
  
  FUNCTION get_attr_name_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata     ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype     ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info   REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output      VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
    v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
    
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
      pos            => p_index,
      prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
      scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
      len            => v_attr_info.len,
      csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
      csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
      attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
      aname          => v_attr_info.aname
    );
    RETURN v_attr_info.aname;
  END;
        
  FUNCTION get_attr_value_at(
    p_anydata IN ANYDATA,
    p_index   IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_anydata   ANYDATA := p_anydata;
    v_anytype   ANYTYPE;
    v_type_info REFLECTION.TYPE_INFO;
    v_output    VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    v_anytype := Get_Type( v_anydata );
    v_type_info := Get_Info( v_anytype );
        
    IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_type_info.COUNT THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    
    v_anydata.PIECEWISE;
    
    FOR i IN 1 .. p_index LOOP
      DECLARE
        v_attr_typeid PLS_INTEGER;
        v_attr_info   REFLECTION.ATTR_INFO;
        v_result_code PLS_INTEGER;
      BEGIN
        v_attr_typeid := v_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
          pos            => i,
          prec           => v_attr_info.prec,
          scale          => v_attr_info.scale,
          len            => v_attr_info.len,
          csid           => v_attr_info.csid,
          csfrm          => v_attr_info.csfrm,
          attr_elt_type  => v_attr_info.attr_elt_type,
          aname          => v_attr_info.aname
        );

        IF DEBUG THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Attribute ' || i || ': '
            || v_attr_info.aname
            || ' (type ' || v_attr_typeid || ')'
          );
        END IF;

        CASE v_attr_typeid
        WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value NUMBER;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetNumber( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value );
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetVarchar2( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN v_value;
            END IF;
          END;
         WHEN DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
          DECLARE
            v_value DATE;
          BEGIN
            v_result_code := v_anydata.GetDate( v_value );
            IF i = p_index THEN
              RETURN TO_CHAR( v_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
            END IF;
          END;
        ELSE
          RETURN NULL;
        END CASE;
      END;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
END;
/

For the following input
DECLARE
   list_of_books table_of_books;
   idx           PLS_INTEGER := 1;
   p_anydata     ANYDATA;
   p_attr_name   VARCHAR2(30);
   p_attr_value  VARCHAR2(4000);
   
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  
  list_of_books := table_of_books(
    book(
      'First book',
      'Me',
      'Simple Ones',
      94321,
      DATE '1970-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the First book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the First book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Second book',
      'You',
      'Intermediate Ones',
      55555,
      DATE '2020-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Second book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Third book',
      NULL,
      'Advanced Ones',
      77777,
      DATE '2099-12-31' + INTERVAL '0 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND,
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Third book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the Third book'
        ),
       book_page(
          3,
          'This is the page 3 of the Third book'
        )
      )
    )
  );
  

  FOR book_no IN 1 .. list_of_books.COUNT LOOP
    p_anydata := ANYDATA.ConvertObject( list_of_books(book_no) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Book ' || book_no || ':' );
    FOR attr_no IN 1 .. REFLECTION.get_size( p_anydata ) LOOP      
      p_attr_name  := REFLECTION.get_attr_name_at( p_anydata, attr_no );
      p_attr_value := REFLECTION.get_attr_value_at( p_anydata, attr_no );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '  ' || p_attr_name || ': ' || p_attr_value );

      -- how can I iterate book_pages here without explicitly declaring a table_of_book_pages type variable?
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

END;
/

I expect the following output:
Book 1:
  TITLE: First book
  AUTHOR: Me
  SUBJECT: Simple Ones
  BOOK_ID: 94321
  FIRST_PUBLISHED: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  BOOK_PAGES:
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 1,
      CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the First book
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 2,
      CONTENT: This is the page 2 of the First book
Book 2:
  TITLE: Second book
  AUTHOR: You
  SUBJECT: Intermediate Ones
  BOOK_ID: 55555
  FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2020-01-01 00:00:00
  BOOK_PAGES:
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 1,
      CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the Second book
Book 3:
  TITLE: Third book
  AUTHOR:
  SUBJECT: Advanced Ones
  BOOK_ID: 77777
  FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2099-12-31 23:59:59
  BOOK_PAGES:
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 1,
      CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the Third book
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 2,
      CONTENT: This is the page 2 of the Third book
    PAGE:
      PAGE_ID: 3,
      CONTENT: This is the page 3 of the Third book

The goal of the implementation is to handle this in a generic way, supporting any type of named collections. Is this achievable without explicitly declaring variables of the collection data type?


Is this achievable without explicitly declaring variables of the collection data type?

No, the ANYDATA type has the methods:


MEMBER FUNCTION GetCollection(
   self         IN ANYDATA,
   col          OUT NOCOPY "<collection_type>")
   RETURN       PLS_INTEGER;



MEMBER FUNCTION GetObject(
   self         IN ANYDATA,
   obj          OUT NOCOPY "<object_type>")
   RETURN       PLS_INTEGER;



Both of them require you to pass in an variable with the correct data-type so there does not appear to be any way to perform a piecewise iteration through an ANYDATA object to retrieve the object or collection attributes in a generic way.

There is a partial solution in this answer but, as it notes, you need to hard-code the data-type for it to work.

That's too bad. What about getting the named collection data type as a VARCHAR (in this case table_of_book_pages) so that we can then pass it through an immediate execution? Is this doable/recommended?

@JoaoPereira The problem is that list_of_books(i) is converted to an ANYDATA object and iterated piecewise and when you do that, the only way to get the table_of_book_pages value for the list_of_books(i).book_pages attribute is to use the ANYDATA methods and those require you to use known types. You cannot convert the collection to a VARCHAR using ANYDATA... (maybe XML? but I don't know.)

You can convert the objects to XML without knowing the structure:
DECLARE
  list_of_books table_of_books;
  v_output CLOB;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  
  list_of_books := table_of_books(
    book(
      'First book',
      'Me',
      'Simple Ones',
      94321,
      DATE '1970-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the First book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the First book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Second book',
      'You',
      'Intermediate Ones',
      55555,
      DATE '2020-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Second book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Third book',
      NULL,
      'Advanced Ones',
      77777,
      DATE '2099-12-31' + INTERVAL '0 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND,
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Third book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the Third book'
        ),
       book_page(
          3,
          'This is the page 3 of the Third book'
        )
      )
    )
  );
  
  SELECT XMLELEMENT(
           "OBJECTS",
           XMLAGG(XMLTYPE(VALUE(t)))
         ).getClobVal() AS output
  INTO   v_output
  FROM   TABLE(list_of_books) t;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_output);
END;
/

Which outputs:
<OBJECTS><BOOK>
  <TITLE>First book</TITLE>
  <AUTHOR>Me</AUTHOR>
  <SUBJECT>Simple Ones</SUBJECT>
  <BOOK_ID>94321</BOOK_ID>
  <FIRST_PUBLISHED>1970-01-01 00:00:00</FIRST_PUBLISHED>
  <BOOK_PAGES>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>1</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 1 of the First book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>2</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 2 of the First book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
  </BOOK_PAGES>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>Second book</TITLE>
  <AUTHOR>You</AUTHOR>
  <SUBJECT>Intermediate Ones</SUBJECT>
  <BOOK_ID>55555</BOOK_ID>
  <FIRST_PUBLISHED>2020-01-01 00:00:00</FIRST_PUBLISHED>
  <BOOK_PAGES>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>1</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 1 of the Second book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
  </BOOK_PAGES>
</BOOK>
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>Third book</TITLE>
  <AUTHOR/>
  <SUBJECT>Advanced Ones</SUBJECT>
  <BOOK_ID>77777</BOOK_ID>
  <FIRST_PUBLISHED>2099-12-31 23:59:59</FIRST_PUBLISHED>
  <BOOK_PAGES>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>1</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 1 of the Third book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>2</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 2 of the Third book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
    <BOOK_PAGE>
      <BOOK_PAGE>3</BOOK_PAGE>
      <CONTENT>This is the page 3 of the Third book</CONTENT>
    </BOOK_PAGE>
  </BOOK_PAGES>
</BOOK>
</OBJECTS>


If you want (approximately) your expected output:
DECLARE
  list_of_books table_of_books;
  v_xml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  
  list_of_books := table_of_books(
    book(
      'First book',
      'Me',
      'Simple Ones',
      94321,
      DATE '1970-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the First book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the First book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Second book',
      'You',
      'Intermediate Ones',
      55555,
      DATE '2020-01-01',
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Second book'
        )
      )
    ),
    book(
      'Third book',
      NULL,
      'Advanced Ones',
      77777,
      DATE '2099-12-31' + INTERVAL '0 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND,
      table_of_book_pages(
        book_page(
          1,
          'This is the page 1 of the Third book'
        ),
        book_page(
          2,
          'This is the page 2 of the Third book'
        ),
       book_page(
          3,
          'This is the page 3 of the Third book'
        )
      )
    )
  );

  FOR r IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   XMLTABLE(
             '//*'
             PASSING (
               (
                 SELECT XMLELEMENT(
                          "OBJECTS",
                          XMLAGG(XMLTYPE(VALUE(t)))
                        )
                 FROM   TABLE(list_of_books) t    
               )
             )
             COLUMNS
               key   VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'name()',
               value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH 'text()',
               depth NUMBER(5,0) PATH 'count(ancestor-or-self::*)'
           )
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD(' ', 2 * r.depth - 2, ' ') || r.key || ': ' || r.value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
OBJECTS: 
  BOOK: 
    TITLE: First book
    AUTHOR: Me
    SUBJECT: Simple Ones
    BOOK_ID: 94321
    FIRST_PUBLISHED: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    BOOK_PAGES: 
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 1
        CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the First book
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 2
        CONTENT: This is the page 2 of the First book
  BOOK: 
    TITLE: Second book
    AUTHOR: You
    SUBJECT: Intermediate Ones
    BOOK_ID: 55555
    FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2020-01-01 00:00:00
    BOOK_PAGES: 
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 1
        CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the Second book
  BOOK: 
    TITLE: Third book
    AUTHOR: 
    SUBJECT: Advanced Ones
    BOOK_ID: 77777
    FIRST_PUBLISHED: 2099-12-31 23:59:59
    BOOK_PAGES: 
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 1
        CONTENT: This is the page 1 of the Third book
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 2
        CONTENT: This is the page 2 of the Third book
      BOOK_PAGE: 
        BOOK_PAGE: 3
        CONTENT: This is the page 3 of the Third book

fiddle

The end goal of this exercise was to serialize this to JSON (and other serialization formats). Would that be possible under this approach?

@JoaoPereira Not easily if you want it generic - see this answer. You may be able to write a solution using Java and then embed the Java into the database but there isn't a simple Oracle-only solution.
